# Why AC voltage is always divisible by 11?

Tags: ac

I started doing by B-Tech today and in the first class my professor asked me this question:

**Why AC voltage is always divisible by 11?**

And google searches gave me multiple answers so I would want to know what is the actual reason for this.

Comment: 230/11 = 20.909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090909090.....

Comment: Always where? :) there is a lot of standards, someone not divisible by 11

Comment: More context would be helpful. The sentence of your professor doesn't make lot of sense otherwise. I guess he means *mains AC nominal voltage*. And, as other comments have already pointed out, this depends on the country you live in.

Comment: *"my professor asked me this question"* - is he also going to give you the answer? That might be more illuminating. [Here is a list of nominal voltages worldwide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country), many of which are not exactly divisible by 11.

Comment: All we know is that they live in a country where mains is either 110 or 220V :( That narrows it down a little...

Comment: So that your amp can be calibrated up to 11.

Comment: Any real number is divisible by 11.

Comment: @BrianDrummond For those that don't know or that don't get the joke (as I didn't until a couple of years ago): [Up to eleven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven). :-D

Comment: @Brian Drummond, The question refers to the preferred voltage levels in India: 110V, 220v, 11kV, 33kV, 66kV, 132kV, 440kV, and relates to the (rounded) form factor (= 1.1); although, the last bit may be a myth!

Answer (score 3):

As I said in a comment, without more context the statement of your professor is *plainly wrong* under many point of views.

First of all ***AC voltage is divisible by 11*** by itself doesn't make sense because:

1. There is no specification of what value are you referring to: peak value (amplitude)? RMS value? Peak-to-peak value?
2. The value is a real number, not an integer, so when you say, for example, 110V it would be 110.3, 109.4, etc. in practice.

So let's fill-in some gaps and let's guess he is talking about *mains AC RMS nominal value*. Even in this case, without further context, the statement is wrong, as you can see by browsing these articles on Wikipedia:

- [Mains Electricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity)
  and in particular this part:

  - [Mains Electricity standardization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity#Standardisation)
- [Mains Electricity by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country)
  and in particular this table:

  - [Table of mains voltages and frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country#Table_of_mains_voltages_and_frequencies)

So there is no technical reason why some specific value would be better than another by an *integer divisibility* point of view. Why countries have AC mains with the value they have is related mostly to history and the need to keep backward compatibility with older appliances when harmonization and changes to the distribution networks became necessary (as in Europe, when EU integration became stronger).